# If Column A1 has some value then Column B1, C1 is mandatory to have value

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance :
My question is : if Column A1,A2,A3.......A nTh has some value then Column B1, B2......, C1,C2....... are mandatory to have value and if A1 is empty then Column B1, C1 should be empty.
I have written a vba code for this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim i As Integer

If ActiveSheet.Name = "ABC" Then

    lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For Each rngCell In Range("A1:A" & lngLstRow)
    
        i = 1
         Do Until i > 2
        
        If rngCell.Value <> "" And rngCell.Offset(0, i) = "" Then
            
            MsgBox ("Please enter value in cell " & rngCell.Offset(0, i).Address)
            
            rngCell.Offset(0, i).Select
           ' Next
          'rngCell.Offset(0, i).Select.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
           
        Cancel = True
           If Cancel = True Then
           GoTo Last
           End If
        ElseIf rngCell.Value = vbNullString And rngCell.Offset(0, i) <> "" Then
            
            MsgBox ("Please enter value in cell " & rngCell.Address)
            
            rngCell.Select
           ' Next
          'rngCell.Offset(0, i).Select.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
           
        Cancel = True
        If Cancel = True Then
           GoTo Last
           End If
    
    End If
  
   i = i + 1
   
   Loop
    

    Next rngCell
     
    
End If
Last:
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: R/Sir, I want to write VBA code. if cell A1 has some value then cell B1, C1, D1 is mandatory. if there is no any value in cell A1 then there cells are not mandatory. Thanks in advance